# discord.py: How to count up all values in a JSON file?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a money bot and I want to count up all values together.

My code now:

```
@bot.command()
async def stats(ctx):
    with open('casinomoney.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    for k, v in users.items():
        statscash = int(users[k]['Cash'])
        statsbank = int(users[k]['Bank'])
        statstotal = int(users[k]['Total'])
        break
    print(f'Cash: {statscash}')
    print(f'Bank: {statsbank}')
    print(f'Total: {statstotal}')
```

My json file:

```
{
    "305354423801217025": {
        "Bank": 1001,
        "Cash": 0,
        "Total": 1001
    },
    "369910055665008652": {
        "Bank": 1001,
        "Cash": 0,
        "Total": 1001
    }
}
```

For `Bank` for example, it should be 2002 at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

omit the `break` statement and also when you're iterating over your `users` dictionary you should avoid accessing key by `users[k]['Cash']` instead you can directly use `v['Cash']`.

```
@bot.command()
async def stats(ctx):
    with open("casinomoney.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    statscash = 0
    statsbank = 0
    statstotal = 0

    for k, v in users.items():

        statscash += int(v["Cash"])
        statsbank += int(v["Bank"])
        statstotal += int(v["Total"])

    print(f"Cash: {statscash}")
    print(f"Bank: {statsbank}")
    print(f"Total: {statstotal}")
```

### Output:

```
Cash: 0
Bank: 2002
Total: 2002
```